# Can particular word be detected even if there are some letters in front or back of a word? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, bots, discord

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "detect":
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "detected")
```

This is my code for making discord bot by python (skipped) and i want to detect the word 'detect'
I succeeded to detect that word, but it cannot detect when some other letters are in front or back of that word.
(e.g. some detect thing)

Is there any solution to detect the word 'detect' even there are some other letters?

Comment: Have you tried: if "detect" in message.content:

Comment: Note that `"detect" in "undetectable"` is `True`, which might or might not be what you want, especially since you mention "word".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this should work:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "detect" in message.content:
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "detected")
```